# How did my teacher find this answer?

Tags: probability

> You play a game using a standard six-sided die. You start with 0
>   points. Before every roll, you decide whether you want to continue the
>   game or end it and keep your points. After each roll, if you rolled 6,
>   then you lose everything and the game ends. Otherwise, add the score
>   from the die to your total points and continue/stop the game.
>
> When should one stop playing this game?

I'd like to ask some questions concerning this question. Let me show how my teacher solved it.

Let $X$ represents the number that comes up on the die.

Therefore the game continues as long as $X<6$,

So, $P(X=6)=nCr  p^r q^{n-r}$ where $r = 1$

Hence we have that

$\dfrac{1}{6}=nC_1 \times \dfrac{1}{6} \times \biggr (\dfrac{5}{6}\biggr )^{n-1}$

Which gives

$n = 1$

However, the fact that I didn't mention that **one wants to maximize total score**.I also don't have any clue/thinking regarding what she found. Could you explain?

Comment: You should ask your teacher what $n$ represents ...

Comment: The 'solution' given, from how I'm reading it, only shows that the probability of rolling exactly one six is 1/6 just when the number of rolls (n) is 1. It seems that P(X=6) is being used in two different ways; first in an equation implying that it means 'the probability of at some point rolling a six and losing', but then being set to 1/6 implying that it is actually the probability of rolling a six on any given role. It seems unlikely that this is intended to be a solution to the problem given; more likely you (or possibly the teacher) misunderstood something.

Comment: @Ian could you be more clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to make this decision is to calculate the expected value of the next roll (i.e., on average, how many points will the next roll give you). Let's say at the moment you have $y$ points. Then the next roll, if it's a 6, will take you down to zero, so it'll give you $-y$ points; otherwise, you'll get between $1$ and $5$ points depending on what you roll. The expected value is then:

$$\frac16 \cdot 1 +\frac16 \cdot 2 +\frac16 \cdot 3 +\frac16 \cdot 4 +\frac16 \cdot 5 +\frac16 \cdot (-y) = \frac{15-y}6$$
Thus, if $y>15$, the expected value is negative; if $y<15$, it's positive; if $y=15$, it's zero.

So if you use this decisionmaking process, you'll stop playing when your score is greater than $15$.

Comment: So, is that answer incorrect?

Comment: @Busi Which answer?

Comment: $n = 1$ That's it

Comment: @Busi What is $n$?

Comment: I don't know. see my solution, maybe you get what it is

Comment: @Busi You used $n$. What did you mean when you used it?

Comment: @Busi even if the problem is that you’re required to choose how many rolls you make at the beginning rather than having the option to quit each round , (so the answer would be in the form $n$ equals something, where $n$ is the number of rolls), $n=1$ is certainly wrong. In that case choices of $5$ or $6$ rolls are both optimal in terms of expected value.

Comment: For those who care, the expected final score when following this stopping strategy is a lot less than $15$, namely $\frac{2893395172951}{470184984576}\approx 6.15$

Answer (score 0):

An older thread, but it caught my attention.  As response to 'what do the teacher's calculations mean', the equation given is the 'probability mass function' for a 'binomial distribution'. It gives the probability for something happening exactly x times after n independent tries.  So they are setting the equation to calculate the odds of getting exactly one success after n tries.  Success in this case probably means rolling a 6, since they used the chance of 1/6 for p.  Then they set it equal to 1/6 and found n to be one, which means that for there to be a 1/6 chance of rolling a 6, roll one time.

This doesn't make sense in the context of the problem.  Any number of 6s from 1 or more results in a loss, so calculating the odds of getting exactly one 6 isn't helpful.  To apply the binomial distribution properly here, it would make more sense to look at X=0, which would be the odds of getting 0 6s after n rolls.  You could multiply that probability by 3*n to see the expected value after n rolls, because you get an average of 3 more points for every non-6 roll. For any other possibility from X=1 to X=N, the expected value will be 0 so you can ignore it.  This setup doesn't actually give us anything to solve for, so I tried it for a few values of N.

1   2.5

2   4.166666667

3   5.208333333

4   5.787037037

5   6.02816358

6   6.02816358

7   5.860714592

8   5.581632945

9   5.232780886

It keeps getting smaller after that.  What these numbers mean is that the optimum number of rolls will either be 5 or 6.  But this also doesn't make sense.  We get to choose whether to continue after knowing what's happened so far, not how many times we're going to roll at the start.

It looks like the answer and comment calculations are correct, by monte carlo simulation.  By taking the average result of 10 million games where the strategy is 'get this much or more, then stop', the results were:

Strat: 1 Average: 2.5008403

Strat: 2 Average: 2.888477

Strat: 3 Average: 3.3100481

Strat: 4 Average: 3.764001

Strat: 5 Average: 4.2490252

Strat: 6 Average: 4.7643912

Strat: 7 Average: 5.052462

Strat: 8 Average: 5.3197232

Strat: 9 Average: 5.5491636

Strat: 10 Average: 5.7435783

Strat: 11 Average: 5.895863

Strat: 12 Average: 6.0029681

Strat: 13 Average: 6.0797659

Strat: 14 Average: 6.1288855

Strat: 15 Average: 6.1540599

Strat: 16 Average: 6.1538515

Strat: 17 Average: 6.1333194

Strat: 18 Average: 6.0968872

Strat: 19 Average: 6.0406913

Strat: 20 Average: 5.9715317

Using this VBA program:

```
Sub Monte()
Dim Score As Long, Strat As Long, Die As Long, Total As Long
Dim i As Long
Randomize
For Strat = 1 To 20
Total = 0
    For i = 1 To 10000000
        Score = 0
        Do
            Die = Int((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
            If Die = 6 Then
                Score = 0
                Exit Do
            Else
                Score = Score + Die
            End If
            'Debug.Print ("D: " & Die & " S: " & Score)
            If Score >= Strat Then Exit Do
        Loop
        Total = Total + Score
    Next i
Debug.Print ("Strat: " & Strat & " Average: " & Total / (i - 1))
Next Strat
End Sub
```